# amcharts4 ColumnSeries fixed width

Tags: amcharts

I'm building a Gantt chart with AmCharts4, based on this demo:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart/

It's basically an *inversed* bar chart... My problem is that I have many tasks in the Gantt so the horizontal bars are squeezed and i'm obliged to use a zoom on the vertical axis. I would like to have a fixed height of the bars and an html scrollbar on the vertical axis, without zooming or panning. Do you have any idea?

[image]

thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... you want a scrollbar, but you don't want it to pan when the user scrolls? So what is it supposed to do?

Comment: I try to explain better, the main point is to have the green bar with a fixed height (say 50px), what I really don't want is zooming/scaling, as you can see in the picture that is the default view. I prefer to have a native html scrollbar with fixed bar height but if it's not possible amcharts' one is fine, just for panning.

Comment: Looking at the title, do you mean "fixed height" fo gantt chart rows/bars?

Comment: It depends on the point of view :) you're right it's the fixed height of the gantt row but in reality is the fixed width of the chart column, as I used amcharts ColumnSeries

Answer (score 2):

I don't think, that is possible with plain amcharts, because the chart is rendered in the area you provide. I think its possible by setting the height of the chart `<div>` dynamically, according to the size of the data.

The chart the should be rerendering itself to fit the new height.

```js
const data = [{
    // your data
  }, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}];

// chart initialisation, etc.

// after setting data
document.getElementById('chart').style.height = `${data.length * 50}px`;
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#chart {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK that would be a trick. I'm open to use amcharts scrollbar, but I want to disable zoom and keep pan only, you think is possible? Anyway i'm thinking that amcharts maybe is a good choice for a gantt chart...

Comment: I don't know if that solution works with amcharts. Disabling zoom can be done with setting `cursor.behavior` ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/chart-cursor/#Zooming_panning)). If you want to disable wheelable zoom (which is enabled on some charts by default) you can use `chart.wheelable` ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/chart/#wheelable_property)). Hope that helps.